# SwiftUI - onChange not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos

Adding the code first to help better understand the problem.

```
struct MainSetupView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: MainViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch viewModel.state {
            case .idle:
                Color.clear.onAppear(perform: { viewModel.prepare() })
            case .loading:
                ProgressView()
            case .showMessage(let messageType, let messageText):
                ErrorHandlingView(messageType: messageType, messageText: messageText)
            }
        }.onAppear() {
            viewModel.state = .idle
        }
    }
}

struct ErrorHandlingView: View {
    @State var messageType: String
    var messageText: String

    @State private var messageViewImageDetails: (imageName: String, isSystemImage: Bool) = (imageName: "", isSystemImage: false)

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MessageViewWithActions(imageName: messageViewImageDetails.imageName, isSystemImage: messageViewImageDetails.isSystemImage, mainMessageText: messageText)
        }.onChange(of: messageType) {_ in
            self.messageViewImageDetails = getImageForError()
            // call more functions
        }
    }
    
    private func getImageForError() -> (imageName: String, isSystemImage: Bool) {
        var imageName = ""
        var isSystemImage = false
        
        switch messageType {
        case "noInternetError":
            imageName = "xmark.icloud"
            isSystemImage = true
        case "userSignedOut":
            imageName = "person.crop.circle.fill.badge.xmark"
            isSystemImage = true
        case "userSignedIn":
            imageName = "person.crop.circle.badge.checkmark"
            isSystemImage = true
        // more cases.
        default:
            imageName = "info.circle"
            isSystemImage = true
        }
        
        return (imageName: imageName, isSystemImage: isSystemImage)
    }
}
```

If "MainSetupView" is open and I receive a message i.e. .showMessage, "ErrorHandlingView" is displayed and I set "messageType" and "messageText" while calling ErrorHandlingView. While first message is being displayed, let's say I receive another message and "ErrorHandlingView" gets called again, now with a different message type. However "onChange(of: messageType)" in "ErrorHandlingView" never gets called.

"onChange(of: messageType)" calls a function "getImageForError" which tells the app which image to display based on the value of messageType. Since code in onChange is not getting executed, "getImageForError" never gets called and hence "messageViewImageDetails" is never populated which results in view without image.

Any idea why is .onChange() not being executed? What am I doing wrong?

Note: I have lots of code and I am sharing pieces of code which I thought would be helpful. Let me know if more code is needed.

***Edit***: Adding code for MessageViewWithActions.

```
struct MessageViewWithActions: View {
    // Image properties
    var imageName: String?
    var isSystemImage: Bool = false
    
    // Text properties
    var mainMessageText: String?

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Text("")
                VStack {
                    if let imageName = imageName {
                        if isSystemImage {
                            Image(systemName: imageName)
                        } else {
                            Image(imageName)
                        }
                    }
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity).padding(.bottom, 8)
                
                if let mainMessageText = mainMessageText {
                    Text(mainMessageText).font(.subheadline).fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is ```MessageViewWithActions```

Comment: It's a view which shows Image on top, text message below it and action button below it if provided. It's a lot of code in "MessageViewWithActions" hence I skipped it thinking it's not needed. But in short, "MessageViewWithActions" takes in image name and text and displays it on the view. Since it's a reusable struct, I have everything in separate structs.

Comment: 1. It might be helpful to post that code to help people figure it out.
2. Is there a reason you have the onChange on the VStack instead of the MessageViewWithActions?

Comment: Added code for MessageViewWithActions. I tried calling onChange on MessageViewWithActions instead of VStack, but it didn't work.

Comment: some observations: you should have `@ObservedObject var viewModel: MainViewModel` in `MainSetupView`.
In `ErrorHandlingView` you don't change the `messageType`, so I suppose `.onChange(of: messageType)` 
does not get called. Depending on what you want, you could use `.onAppear {...}` instead.

Comment: @StateObject is working for viewModel and "ErrorHandlingView" is being called and I do see it on the view. I just don't see the image since image gets set in onChange of "ErrorHandlingView". onAppear works when "ErrorHandlingView" is opened first time. However if "ErrorHandlingView" is already open and value for messageType changes, then onAppear does not get called since it's already open.

Comment: use a `@Binding` then instead of `@State var messageType`, and adjust the code accordingly. I still maintain that you should have `@ObservedObject var viewModel: MainViewModel` in `MainSetupView`.

Comment: Changing messageType to Binding var worked. However why do you think "viewModel" should be "ObservedObject" instead of "StateObject"? Am new to SwiftUI and from what I read, we should use "ObservedObject" only if there is a need to pass "viewModel" down to child views. In this case "viewModel" is just being used by MainSetupView, so I kept it as StateObject.

Comment: Actually, you do not need `@State` variables in your ErrorHandlingView. These values can be let constants. Just set these when creating the SwiftUI view, i.e. pass values from parent to child view. These values can be closures as well which are used to handle user actions. You use `@State` only when these values represent _private_ and _mutable_ state of the view, i.e., only the view knows about it (and potentially, indirectly, child views via Bindings). `@State` variables should always have a _private_ access modifier.

Answer (score 4):

Changing messageType to Binding var instead of State var worked. Sharing updated code for future:

```
struct MainSetupView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: MainViewModel
    @State var messageType: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            switch viewModel.state {
            case .idle:
                Color.clear.onAppear(perform: { viewModel.prepare() })
            case .loading:
                ProgressView()
            case .showMessage(_, let messageText):
                ErrorHandlingView(messageType: messageType, messageText: messageText)
            }
        }.onAppear() {
            viewModel.state = .idle
        }.onReceive(viewModel.$state, perform: { (value) in
            switch value {
            case .showMessage(let messageType, _):
                self.messageType = messageType
            case .idle, .loading:
                print("")
            }
        })
    }
}

struct ErrorHandlingView: View {
    @Binding var messageType: String
    var messageText: String

    @State private var messageViewImageDetails: (imageName: String, isSystemImage: Bool) = (imageName: "", isSystemImage: false)

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MessageViewWithActions(imageName: messageViewImageDetails.imageName, isSystemImage: messageViewImageDetails.isSystemImage, mainMessageText: messageText)
        }.onChange(of: messageType) {_ in
            self.messageViewImageDetails = getImageForError()
            // call more functions
        }
    }
    
    private func getImageForError() -> (imageName: String, isSystemImage: Bool) {
        var imageName = ""
        var isSystemImage = false
        
        switch messageType {
        case "noInternetError":
            imageName = "xmark.icloud"
            isSystemImage = true
        case "userSignedOut":
            imageName = "person.crop.circle.fill.badge.xmark"
            isSystemImage = true
        case "userSignedIn":
            imageName = "person.crop.circle.badge.checkmark"
            isSystemImage = true
        // more cases.
        default:
            imageName = "info.circle"
            isSystemImage = true
        }
        
        return (imageName: imageName, isSystemImage: isSystemImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way

Comment: just great, you turned my comment into your very own answer.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine - I did reply to you in the comment that your answer worked :). I just wanted to leave an answer for future reference incase if anyone comes looking for a solution to same issue.

Comment: `@StateObject var viewModel: MainViewModel` ? 
You didn't initialise  `viewModel` in MainSetupView. Can't work. Please read here for more info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject